# How is program creating then writing to file

Tags: c#, c, file-io

I was analyzing the way a C program in Linux writes to a file and I summarize it to:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "restart.h"
#define CREATE_FLAGS (O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND)
#define CREATE_MODE (S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH)

int main(void) {

   int fd;

   fd = open("my.file", CREATE_FLAGS, CREATE_MODE);

   dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);

   r_close(fd) ;

   write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Hello World", 11) ;

   return 0;
}
```

the two small header files r_close.c and restart.h are in [THIS](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/81397375/headers.zip) link.

**So my question is** I will like to know how the program is writing to the file. For example what is the difference of doing it in c# as:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var file = System.IO.File.OpenWrite("my.file");
        file.Write(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello World"), 0, 11);
        file.Close();
    }
```

I looked at the description of dup2 method in many links such as at http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/dup2.3.asp  and I am having a hard time trying to understand what it basically does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The dup2() function duplicates an open file descriptor. Specifically,
>   it provides an alternate interface to the service provided by the
>   fcntl() function using the F_DUPFD constant command value, with
>   fildes2 for its third argument. The duplicated file descriptor shares
>   any locks with the original.

The call:

```
fid = dup2(fildes, fildes2);
```

is equivalent to:

```
close(fildes2);
fid = fcntl(fildes, F_DUPFD, fildes2);
```

What this means is that we have modified the table that the OS has to hold the open files descriptor. It uses the `fcntl()` function. fcntl() provides control of open file descriptors. Basicly it copies an int to an int. **But** it does it using a system call; as it modifies an OS resource. Your saying to the system: You know that Index in the FileTable? Yes? well copy the FilePointer to another Index. ( A few other things also but I'll have to ignore that for now.)

Re: the second part of your question, What is the difference?

They basically do the same thing. Probably exactly the same chars are written to the file. It does do one extra thing. That is it `dup2()` `STDOUT_FILENO`. to a file. That changes what the standard output is. If I'm not mistaken that code will redirect all output that would normally go to the console to `fd`, in your case `"my.file"`. That's the main difference between the **C#** and **C** done you listed.

It should also be noted that the whole `dup2()` in this sample is kind of pointless if all you are concerned with is to write *"Hello World"* to a file. It is sorta like going `int x = 5; int y = x; Console.WriteLine(y);`. The extra step doesn't anything in your example.

Another, more general difference, is that C# hides a-lot of the low level stuff from you the programmer. While coding in C, you will be able to do lower level file and system manipulation with more ease. The downside is that you have to do more coding of the lower level stuff. While mostly you don't really care exactly how that stuff happens, rather that it does indeed happen. So often, it's quicker to code in C# because all the low level stuff is handled nicely for you already. **-- Sorta off topic point that may help you understand**

Finally I will hazard a guess that;

> I was analyzing the way a C program in Linux writes to a file and I
>   summarize it to:

You were analyzing a program that deals with I/O manipulation, rather than ordinary writing to a file. That would explain the `dup2()`.

Comment: You where right. after calling the `dup2` method everything I ouput to the console gets writen to the file! In other words `printf("Foo");` will be written to the file instead than to the console!

Answer (score 2):

```
fd = open("my.file", CREATE_FLAGS, CREATE_MODE);
```

This creates and opens the file, opening it for writing in append more where every write occurs at the end of the file.

```
dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
```

This copies the file descriptor for the newly-opened file on top of the descriptor that is the program's standard output descriptor. These two descriptors now reference the same opened file description.

```
r_close(fd) ;
```

This closes the descriptor obtained from `open`, leaving the copy intact.

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Hello World", 11) ;
```

This writes to the program's standard output stream, which is now the same open file description we got from opening the new file.